# Excel in C#: How to programmatically fit rows/colums based on number of lines in cell

Tags: c#, excel

Currently I am writing a program that outputs some data to a spreadsheet, and some of the cells have multiple lines written to them. When I use the Rows.AutoFit() and Columns.AutoFit() methods from the range object, it resizes the borders so that all of the contents of the cells are visible, but it doesn't resize it so that the cells don't break up the lines into smaller lines, and it leaves a lot of white space at the top of the cells. Is there a way to resize the rows and columns programmatically to make it more tidy?

Here is the relevant code snippet with a bit of context:

```
if (_output != null)
{
    a = new Excel.Application();
    if(a==null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed.");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        b = a.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        s1 = (Excel.Worksheet)b.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        s1.Name = "Audit";
        s1.Cells[1, 1] = "Computer Name";
        s1.Cells[1, 2] = "Manufacturer";
        s1.Cells[1, 3] = "Motherboard Model (HP)";
        s1.Cells[1, 4] = "Motherboard Model (Other)";
        s1.Cells[1, 5] = "Product Number (HP)";
        s1.Cells[1, 6] = "Serial Number (HP)";
        s1.Cells[1, 7] = "Serial Number (Other)";
        s1.Cells[1, 8] = "CPU";
        s1.Cells[1, 9] = "Cores";
        s1.Cells[1, 10] = "Threads";
        s1.Cells[1, 11] = "Memory";
        s1.Cells[1, 12] = "Graphics Card";
        s1.Cells[1, 13] = "Disk Model(s)";
        s1.Cells[1, 14] = "Disk Size(s)";
        s1.Cells[1, 15] = "Operating System";
        s1.Cells[1, 16] = "Architecture";
        s2 = b.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 1, Type.Missing);
        s2.Name = "uncontactable";
        int totalSheets = a.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
        s1.Move(a.Worksheets[1]);
        for(int c = 0; c < queue.Count; c++)
        {
            row = c + 2;
            specs = new List<string>();
            specs.AddRange(getSpecs(queue[c], _user, _pass));
            foreach(string n in specs)
            {
                if (n.StartsWith("Computer Name: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 1] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Manufacturer: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 2] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Motherboard Model(HP): ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 3] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Motherboard Model(Other): ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 4] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Product Number(HP): ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 5] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Serial Number(HP): ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 6] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Serial Number(Other): ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 7] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("CPU: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 8] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Cores: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 9] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Threads: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 10] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Memory: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 11] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Graphics Card: ") == true)
                {
                    if (s1.Cells[row, 12] == null)
                    {
                        s1.Cells[row, 12] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s1.Cells[row, 12] = s1.Cells[row, 12].Value + "\n" + n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                    }
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Disk Model: ") == true)
                {
                    if (s1.Cells[row, 13] == null)
                    {
                        s1.Cells[row, 13] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s1.Cells[row, 13] = s1.Cells[row, 13].Value + "\n" + n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                    }
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Disk Size: ") == true)
                {
                    if (s1.Cells[row, 14] == null)
                    {
                        s1.Cells[row, 14] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s1.Cells[row, 14] = s1.Cells[row, 14].Value + "\n" + n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                    }
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Operating System: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 15] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
                else if (n.StartsWith("Architecture: ") == true)
                {
                    s1.Cells[row, 16] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                }
            }
        }
        s1.Columns.AutoFit();
        s2.Columns.AutoFit();
        s1.Rows.AutoFit();
        s2.Rows.AutoFit();
        r = s1.Range["A1","P"+row.ToString()];
        r.Columns.AutoFit();
        r.Rows.AutoFit();
        a.DisplayAlerts = false;
        b.SaveAs(_output, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        b.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        a.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(s1);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(s2);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(b);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(a);
    }
}
```

The full code is here: https://pastebin.com/YK15eTqC

and I have attached a screenshot of the resulting .xls file: 
[image: screenshot of .xls the program creates.]

I would prefer it to look like the following screenshot, which is of the same file, but after I modified the rows and columns manually.
[image: screenshot of .xls after manual edit]

Comment: Are you using the default Microsoft library for creating the spreadsheet? That is `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` namespace?

Comment: At the top of the program (not in the snippet) I have this: 

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire contents of your `.cs` file into the original question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here is the code.

```
            if (_output != null)
            {
                a = new Excel.Application();
                if(a==null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed.");
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    b = a.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                    s1 = (Excel.Worksheet)b.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                    s1.Name = "Audit";
                    s1.Cells[1, 1] = "Computer Name";
                    r = s1.Range["A1" , "A1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Computer Name", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 2] = "Manufacturer";
                    r = s1.Range["B1" , "B1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Manufacturer", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 3] = "Motherboard Model (HP)";
                    r = s1.Range["C1" , "C1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Motherboard Model (HP)", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 4] = "Motherboard Model (Other)";
                    r = s1.Range["D1" , "D1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Motherboard Model (Other)", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 5] = "Product Number (HP)";
                    r = s1.Range["E1" , "E1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Product Number (HP)", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 6] = "Serial Number (HP)";
                    r = s1.Range["F1" , "F1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Serial Number (HP)", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 7] = "Serial Number (Other)";
                    r = s1.Range["G1" , "G1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Serial Number (Other)", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 8] = "CPU";
                    r = s1.Range["H1" , "H1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("CPU", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 9] = "Cores";
                    r = s1.Range["I1" , "I1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Cores", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 10] = "Threads";
                    r = s1.Range["J1" , "J1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Threads", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 11] = "Memory";
                    r = s1.Range["K1" , "K1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Memory", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 12] = "Graphics Card";
                    r = s1.Range["L1" , "L1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Graphics Card", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 13] = "Disk Model(s)";
                    r = s1.Range["M1" , "M1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Disk Model(s)", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 14] = "Disk Size(s)";
                    r = s1.Range["N1" , "N1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Disk Size(s)", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 15] = "Operating System";
                    r = s1.Range["O1" , "O1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Operating System", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s1.Cells[1, 16] = "Architecture";
                    r = s1.Range["P1" , "P1"];
                    r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Architecture", new Font("Calibri", 11, FontStyle.Regular)).Width / 7;
                    s2 = b.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 1, Type.Missing);
                    s2.Name = "uncontactable";
                    int totalSheets = a.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
                    s1.Move(a.Worksheets[1]);
                    for(int c = 0; c < queue.Count; c++)
                    {
                        row = c + 2;
                        specs = new List<string>();
                        specs.AddRange(getSpecs(queue[c], _user, _pass));
                        foreach(string n in specs)
                        {
                            if (n.StartsWith("Computer Name: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 1] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 1;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Manufacturer: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 2] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 2;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Motherboard Model(HP): ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 3] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 3;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Motherboard Model(Other): ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 4] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 4;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Product Number(HP): ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 5] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 5;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Serial Number(HP): ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 6] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 6;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Serial Number(Other): ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 7] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 7;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("CPU: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 8] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 8;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Cores: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 9] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 9;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Threads: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 10] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 10;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Memory: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 11] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 11;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Graphics Card: ") == true)
                            {
                                ch = Convert.ToString(s1.Cells[row,12].Value);
                                if (ch == null)
                                {
                                    s1.Cells[row, 12] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    s1.Cells[row, 12] = s1.Cells[row, 12].Value + "\n" + n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                }
                                column = 12;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Disk Model: ") == true)
                            {
                                ch = Convert.ToString(s1.Cells[row, 13].Value);
                                if (ch == null)
                                {
                                    s1.Cells[row, 13] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    s1.Cells[row, 13] = s1.Cells[row, 13].Value + "\n" + n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                }
                                column = 13;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Disk Size: ") == true)
                            {
                                ch = Convert.ToString(s1.Cells[row, 14].Value);
                                if (ch == null)
                                {
                                    s1.Cells[row, 14] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    s1.Cells[row, 14] = s1.Cells[row, 14].Value + "\n" + n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                }
                                column = 14;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Operating System: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 15] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 15;
                            }
                            else if (n.StartsWith("Architecture: ") == true)
                            {
                                s1.Cells[row, 16] = n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2);
                                column = 16;
                            }
                            //If text in the cell has dimensions greater than the cell's row and/or column, resize row and/or column to be the same
                            r = s1.Range[getColumnLetter(column)+row.ToString(),getColumnLetter(column)+row.ToString()];
                            if (TextRenderer.MeasureText(s1.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString(), f).Width / 7 > r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth)
                            {
                                r.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(n.Substring(n.IndexOf(':') + 2), f).Width / 7;
                            }
                            for(int d = 1; d <= 16; d++)
                            {
                                ch = Convert.ToString(s1.Cells[row, d].Value);
                                if(ch != null)
                                {
                                    if (((TextRenderer.MeasureText(s1.Cells[row, d].Value.ToString(), f).Height) / 18) * 15 > rh)
                                    {
                                        rh = ((TextRenderer.MeasureText(s1.Cells[row, d].Value.ToString(), f).Height) / 18) * 15;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            r.EntireRow.RowHeight = rh;
                        }
                    }
                    a.DisplayAlerts = false;
                    b.SaveAs(_output, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    b.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                    a.Quit();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(s1);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(s2);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(b);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(a);
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
```

Basically for every column and row I had to check the height and length of the content of individual cells against the row height and column length.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/columnsiautofit-with-multiline-text-and-wrap-text/bb6ee280-a043-4f81-a257-2316cf59313a?auth=1) *very old* but still accurate answer, if you want to use `AutoFit` with multi-line text then you need to enable text wrapping, but this itself means that you have to specify a constant column width which is probably not what you want.

You could use a different character like a pipe to separate the items, otherwise you'll have to use magic numbers and set column widths that way.